# Python Decompressing gzip csv in pandas csv reader

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, python-requests, gzip

The following code works in Python3 but fails in Python2

```
r = requests.get("http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/coinbaseUSD.csv.gz", stream=True)
decompressed_file = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=r.raw)
data = pd.read_csv(decompressed_file, sep=',')
data.columns = ["timestamp", "price" , "volume"]  # set df col headers
return data
```

The error I get in Python2 is the following:

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

The error is on the line where I set data equal to pd.read_csv(...)

Seems to be a pandas error to me

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fetch.py", line 51, in <module>
    print(f.get_historical())
  File "fetch.py", line 36, in get_historical
    data = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 709, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 449, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 818, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1049, in _make_engine

    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1695, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 562, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 760, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 965, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2197, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
io.UnsupportedOperation: seek
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this error on python2. Please provide the full traceback so we can see from where exactly this issue is stemming. All I can say that something somewhere is trying to index an `int` and that's what that `TypeError` exception is complaining about.

Comment: always put full Traceback in qiestion. There are other useful informations.

Comment: you could display `decompressed_file`  to see what you get

Comment: @Abdou stack trace has been updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue from the traceback you posted is related to the fact that the `Response` object's raw attribute is a file-like object that does not support the `.seek` method that typical file objects support. However, when ingesting the file object with `pd.read_csv`, pandas (in python2) seems to be making use of the `seek` method of the provided file object.

You can confirm that the returned response's raw data is not seekable by calling `r.raw.seekable()`, which should normally return `False`.

The way to circumvent this issue may be to wrap the returned data into an `io.BytesIO` object as follows:

```
import gzip
import io
import pandas as pd
import requests

# file_url = "http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/coinbaseUSD.csv.gz"
file_url = "http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/aqoinEUR.csv.gz"
r = requests.get(file_url, stream=True)
dfile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(r.raw.read()))
data = pd.read_csv(dfile, sep=',')

print(data)

            0     1    2
0  1314964052  2.60  0.4
1  1316277154  3.75  0.5
2  1316300526  4.00  4.0
3  1316300612  3.80  1.0
4  1316300622  3.75  1.5
```

As you can see, I used a smaller file from the directory of files available. You can switch this to your desired file.
In any case, `io.BytesIO(r.raw.read())` should be seekable, and therefore should help avoid the `io.UnsupportedOperation` exception you are encountering.

As for the `TypeError` exception, it is inexistent in this snippet of code.

I hope this helps.